# When copy and pasting a range, the open workbook is selected incorrectly using a with statement in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the range from one worksheet and paste it into another workbook  and then do the same for another range in a different workbook. The issue I am having is it is taking what seems to be taking the range from the "most recently opened" workbook rather than selecting the correct one.

See below the following code:

```
Sub CopyTEST()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
Dim rngToCopy1 As Range, rngToCopy2 As Range
Dim wbName1 As String, wbName2 As String

wbName1 = "Book"
wbName2 = "APP"

    For Each wB In Application.Workbooks

        If wB.Name Like wbName2 & "*" Then
            Set Wb1 = wB
            Debug.Print Wb1.Name
        End If

        If wB.Name Like wbName1 & "*" Then
            With wB.Sheets("Sheet1")
                If Left(Right(Cells(6, 4), 4), 2) = "12" Then
                    MsgBox ("12")
                    Set wb2 = wB
                ElseIf Left(Right(Cells(6, 4), 4), 2) = "10" Then
                    MsgBox ("10")
                    Set wb3 = wB
                    Set wb3 = wB
                Else
                    MsgBox ("ERROR")
                    Exit Sub

                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next wB




    With wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngToCopy1 = .Range("A1:II82")
    End With

    With wb3.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngToCopy2 = .Range("A1:II82")
    End With

    With Wb1
        .Sheets("A").Range("A1:II82").Value = rngToCopy2.Value
        .Sheets("B").Range("A1:II82").Value = rngToCopy1.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

The issue I am seeming to have is say we have Book3 where the cells are equal to 12 and then Book4 where the cells are equal to 10. If Book4 is directly open then when we are going through the For loop with each wB, and we are observing Book3, it will take the range from Book4 instead of Book3...

The If statements obvserving the cells in the worksheets are showing correct values when I step into the code, they are just selecting the wrong ranges...

I hope this makes sense... Thanks!

Comment: You need a period in front of `Cells(6, 4)` - otherwise you're not actually referencing `wb.Sheets("Sheet1")` in the `With...End With`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not carrying the parent reference you created on to the cells.

```
        With wB.Sheets("Sheet1")
            If .Cells(6, 4) = "12" Then
                MsgBox ("12")
                Set wb2 = wB
            ElseIf .Cells(6, 4) = "10" Then
                MsgBox ("10")
                Set wb3 = wB
            Else
                MsgBox ("ERROR")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
```

Note `.Cells` not `Cells`. This transfers the workbook/worksheet from the With ... End With to .Cells.

Comment: where do you mean? the .Cells seems to make the macro run successfully?